# C - Linux create sound in kernel mode

Tags: c, linux, audio, kernel, driver

I need o write a kernel mode driver that plays a note when a key is pressed. I can capture keystrokes but I have no idea how to play sound from kernel. What do I have to do to play a sound? I am brand new to creating drivers.

Comment: a driver applies to a given hardware / protocol, which one ?

Comment: @bruno, im afraid I do not know that. How can I found out what hardware/protocol I use?

Comment: what a strange question, how can I guess the computer you use and even the output you want to use too ? Even on my 'simple' PI4 I can produce sound through several outputs/ways. Are you sure you want to implement a driver, or to use one of the already existing features of your computer ?

Comment: @bruno, I definitely do not want to, but I have to. There must be a way to see current hardware, right? I am not sure what you asked, but I can tell my audio controllers names (those lspci shows)

Comment: may I am wrong but for me *write a driver* means *implement a driver*, not *use a driver*. Visibly you want to *use* one, and may be indirectly through a lib

Comment: @bruno The main demand is to make it all in kernel mode. If I won't have to implement my own driver, I think it is fine as long as it plays the notes whenever a key is pressed. If it can only be done from user mode then I guess I'll have to write one of my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need o write a kernel mode driver that plays a note when a key is pressed.

Why?

Seriously, why. What's the reasoning behind this "need"? What's the true reason for the need to play a sound? Maybe there is a better way.

Assuming a PC, with the `pcspkr` module loaded, you can of course call its functions. But if you want to play something through the soundcard, you'll essentially have to "open" an ALSA device (inside the kernel), and call its fops, all along while user space may do the same thing.

Comment: It is a University project and my teacher demands full project in kernel mode. Is it correct that the device driver is already implemented and I just have to find out what this device is and then somehow open it to access it from kernel?

Comment: @Rabter: That depends entirely on the system your thing is running on. On a PC you may, or may not have a physical speaker available, that can beep (or not). To be honest: Creating a "beep" from inside the kernel can be a lot more demanding, than it looks like on first glance. If you have a PC speaker available, then use that. If not: Good luck! – The problem you're dealing with is, that all these devices are meant to be driven from user space. So anything that happens inside the kernel must make sure, that it doesn't interfere with operations initiated from user space.

Comment: @Rabter: To stay on topic. If you follow the path the KIOCSOUND ioctl takes, it eventually ends up at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/vt/keyboard.c#L235 where it actually injects the beep command into the event stream from/to user space, from where it ultimately takes the same path as if things had been initiated from user space.

Comment: I've been studying the source codes you linked there. The problem is, that in order to beep using that function, I must have an input_handler object that requires some functions implemented. In this file, those functions are (as I understand) keyboard event handlers. Those are assigned here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/vt/keyboard.c#L1636

Comment: But I guess I could just use ioctl(fd, KIOCSOUND, (long) argument) since pkspcr module works for me. I just need to find out what fd should be. As I understand, it is the descriptor of one of my ALSA devices. But I do not know how to get it from anywhere

Comment: @Rabter: `ioctl` is a syscall, i.e. comes from userspace. You're overthinking that. Just do, what the ioctl handler does: Call the `kd_mksound` function. This will then go all the way injecting the right event. https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/vt/vt_ioctl.c#L304

Comment: Does no effect. I've tried ```echo -ne '\007'``` without pcspkr module loaded and it still beeped the same way (and also from my headset). I guess, pcspkr should make sound from the system unit, but there is no speaker inside so I guess kd_mksound won't work for me?

Comment: @Rabter: Are you perchance running this in a terminal window on a graphical desktop. If so, then very likely the bell character that goes into the PTS device (that the terminal program connects to on the other end) will trigger the playback of a notification audio file through the soundcard.

Comment: Apparently so. I am running this in standard Ubuntu terminal

Comment: Well there should be a way to make it work. In the end, as I understand, any sound driver just sends a certain number to a certain port (that belongs to the sound card). Does it not?

Comment: @Rabter: No, that's not how it works. For one, ports only existed back on old x86 ISA bus; there's still emulated "ports" for PCI devices and "legacy" ports that allows to run DOS on a modern PC. – And as far as sound devices is concerned: You'll have to fill a buffer with the audio samples, figure out where in physical address space these buffers reside (and in which order), then the sound card may, or may not offer you memory mappings to copy those buffers to, or you've to setup a DMA transfer. And of course the details of all of that are specific and different between each sound card model.

Comment: @Rabter: The only portable way is to send the sound samples to the sound driver. And this sound driver doesn't expect to get force fed audio samples from inside kernel space. It expects all sound samples to go through its device node `fops`.

Comment: @Rabter: I've noticed quite a lot of Linux kernel driver related questions poping up here, all of them full of gleefull naivitee about how messy things tend to be down there, if you get into it deep enough. I can't help but wonder if they're all students attending the same class and doing some homework or end-of-semester project.

Comment: So you are basicly saying it is practically impossible?

Comment: @Rabter: It's not impossible. It's just *a lot* of work. A lot more than if you were operating from userspace. The driver responsible for the piece of hardware in question does does not expect for something else to access the hardware, and it also doesn't expect to be talked to from parts of the kernel other than itself. What you can do is locating the snd_pcm structure, navigate them, and then use the functions documented at https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/sound/kernel-api/alsa-driver-api.html

Comment: OK, I found an old pc speaker and it works this way. I think im gonna leave it so for now.  I am not sure if there is any sense in keepeing this question or re-phrasing it though